# How do I edit MS Access database using Java (NetBeans)

Tags: java, database, ms-access, prepared-statement

I'm trying to edit an MS Access database using some Java code (running NetBeans 7.2.1). I set up the data source and linked it to my database ProjectDatabase using the ODBC tool and named the data source DB, then i run the following code:

import java.sql.*;
public class NewMain {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DB");
       Statement st=con.createStatement();
       String name="roseindia";
       String address="delhi";
       int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into user(name,address)      values('"+name+"','"+address+"')");
       System.out.println("Row is added");
       }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

The code runs without and error and returns the "Row is added" message. The problem is that when I go back to view the database the changes have not taken effect. I have tried this with a code for deleting the data, also to no effect. Has anybody had this problem and knows how to solve it?

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, Microsoft Office 64-bit with all the 64-bit drivers and I have been unable to find any mention of this problem through web searches.

Thanks in advance for any help =)

Comment: check how many rows get added by printing `i` after the executeUpdate() statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are not closing the connection, so that is one problem. Also change your code to:

```
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DB");
   Statement st=con.createStatement();
   con.setAutoCommit(false); //Notice change here
   String name="roseindia";
   String address="delhi";
   int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into user(name,address)      values('"+name+"','"+address+"')");
   con.commit(); //Notice change here
   System.out.println("Row is added");
   con.close(); //Notice change here
```

This will commit the changes to access database, so now you should be able to see data in MS Access.

Read here to know more about best practices for [Closing and Releasing JDBC resources](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/closing_and_releasing_jdbc_resources.html)

Comment: It will auto-commit anyway, agree?

Comment: @SudhanshuUmalkar, yes but for MS-Access it is always better to manually commit